# STM32 5V ADC Input

Tags: circuit-analysis, stm32, adc

The output voltage of MQ-2 smoke sensor is 0-5V.But ADC Vref of STM32F407ZG can only connect to 3.3V.
I design a circuit like this.
[image]

But the input impedance of STM32 ADC depends on both frequency of adoption and the current temprature，and the datasheet of MQ-2 doesn't indicate the output impedance?so how to choose a best resistance value?

Comment: What is your intended purpose with the 1k resistor on the OPAMP input? Are you under the impression that you're needing to match impedances?

Comment: it's a protective resistance

Comment: Protecting what from what by doing what?

Comment: @brhans it protects the op-amp from over voltage by allowing the ESD clamps to kick in and mitigate the current flow until it does, thus saving the op-amp from getting fried in some cases.

Comment: @JeffreyPhillipsFreeman I'm aware that that's a possibility. I'm trying to get a handle on the OP's thought process, since what they're trying to do & why is not clear from the question - particularly the references to the input & output impedances of the sensor & ADC.

Comment: Note that jellybean SMD parts are so cheap, that in anything but huge volume manufacturing it's often worth putting components even where they're not needed.  I'd personally give myself a series/shunt set of possibilities on both the input and the output, and probably actually *two* shunts in case I wanted a capacitor.  BOM changes are easy, board changes take time and money and unless you run out of area DNP's are free.  Also, an "unnecessary" series element is a great place to probe or temporarily disconnect to test a stage in isolation.

Answer (score 3):

The MQ-2 operates as a current generator - when a combustible gas is nearby, the sensor generates an electrical current in proportion to the amount of gas present. The resistor that is required on the output pin of the sensor is there to convert this current signal into a voltage. It looks like you've confused the role of this in your opamp circuit. The opamp circuit you have is a non-inverting buffer and the input resistor will not properly load the output of the sensor (it is essentially floating). You should either use a non-inverting current converter design, or connect the load resistor between the input and ground instead.

In any event, you don't really need the amplifier to connect the sensor to the STM32. The STM32 has a high impedance ADC input but uses a small (4pF) sample and hold capacitor. It is only the time required to charge this capacitor when the input voltage changes that can affect the precision available. Since the gas sensor output will change very slowly (<100Hz) you can easily sample it with a very long sample and hold time to ensure the capacitor is fully charged to match any changes in the sensor output. Further, since the sensor is not going to be changing much between samples, any effects on accuracy are going to be even further reduced.

The input pin in ADC mode is 5V tolerant, but keep in mind that there is no input clamping circuitry when in analog mode, so if you do go over the maximum input voltage (VDD + 4V) or apply a negative voltage it is important to include an external protection circuit.

Comment: The input pin is not 5 V tolerant in ADC mode. From the datasheet: "FT = 5 V tolerant except when in analog mode or oscillator mode"

Comment: @Arsenal hmm, you're right. In the datasheet it seems to show clamping diodes on the input, but I'm pretty sure the other STM32's I've used didn't have internal clamps when in ADC mode. Will do some more digging.

Comment: This seems headed in a good direction in terms of considering the nature of the sensor.  The real issue, and perhaps the reason the question is closed, is that it has a very incomplete datasheet which characterizes operation at 5v but does not specify a range.  There are suggestions on the net that it may work with a supply as low as 2.5v (at least for the sensor, not sure if the heater can remain 5v then) but definitive official information is scarce.

Comment: With regard to the asker's concern about the ADC, while it probably can work with a high impedance input at a lower sampling rate, ultimately the issue is the conversion rate, *not* the slew rate of the input.  The effective impedance comes from having to re-charge the ADC capacitor *every time*, even if the input voltage is *unchanged*.

Comment: But simply replacing the sensor load resistor with a resistive divider of the same total resistance, designed to tap off 3/5 of its voltage as input to the voltage follower would be a simple, robust solution - it's there in your answer, but could be more explicitly stated.

Comment: @Jon the clamping is going to VDD and not VDD_FT have a look at the reference manual, there is a configuration for each mode of the pin shown. But it doesn't seem to be very consistent.

Answer (score 1):

Only current feedback op-amps have low impedance inputs, this does not appear to be one of those so the inputs should be high impedance. As such the value of the input resistor isn't critical, it is usually just used for overvoltage protection and in some cases can be left out entirely. If you want it there for protection just pick a high value like 100K and you should be good, the specific value isn't critical.

As for the input on the STM32, that isn't too critical either. Yes it will vary somewhat with frequency but unless you're going to drive this thing at MHz frequencies well beyond what would be necessary for a reading from a smoke detector it won't really matter. If you are worried the smoke detector might have its value changing fast enough that it would lower the input impedance significantly you should add in a low-pass filter to simply reject those frequencies anyway, in fact its a good thing to add just to reject noise. The input impedance will be approximately 50k\$\Omega\$ at any reasonable sampling rate for this application  and with the voltage divider you have in place that should work just fine.

Though keep in mind your op-amp here really doesn't serve any useful purpose I'd remove it, your MQ-2 can drive the voltage divider directly and you can skip the op-amp all together.

Comment: Actually, the input impedance of ADCs as found on the STM32 can be surprisingly low, and depends heavily on the ADC clock rate.   Please see the data sheet, as the asker has a real and valid concern which you are dismissing from a point of lacking knowledge.  The asker's dilemma is that the voltage conversion ends intimately combined with either the input or the output impedance... unless they use a second active buffer.  A few STM32's have one on chip.

Comment: The 50kV value I stated was direct from the datasheet. If you have a relevant part of the datasheet that contradicts that please feel free to indicate what that may be.

Comment: You're misreading the data sheet, grabbing the maximum and ignoring the note to see the clock specific formula.   Older STM32's gave you a table of typical actual values which made the horrible news explicit, this one makes you work for it.

Comment: @ChrisStratton The value I pulled was from page 133 BTW.. what page are you refering to, I'll take a look at that.

Comment: @ChrisStratton He is sampling from a smoke detector.. he wont be sampling it at MHz scale frequencies. Worth correcting my language a bit I agree, but for his application if he is sampling at anything even remotely reasonable for what he is doing the ADC input impedance will be close enough to maximum.

Comment: Note that the 50kohm quoted in the data sheet is not the ADC input impedance, it is the maximum output impedance of the voltage source being measured if you want to ensure 1/4LSB accuracy at the maximum sample rate and 12-bit resolution.

Comment: @Jon Ahh my mistake.. I will update my answer. It appears it is 6k ohms correct?